# How do I disable the arrow keys in VIM's "INSERT (paste)" mode?

Tags: vim

This is what I have in my `.vimrc` file for disabling the arrow/cursor keys as a way of forcing me (and the team I work with) to learn Vim's navigation keys/commands.

```
inoremap  <Up>     <NOP>
inoremap  <Down>   <NOP>
inoremap  <Left>   <NOP>
inoremap  <Right>  <NOP>
noremap   <Up>     <NOP>
noremap   <Down>   <NOP>
noremap   <Left>   <NOP>
noremap   <Right>  <NOP>
```

It works great except for that when in `INSERT (paste)` mode (issuing the command `:set paste` and then going to insert mode), the arrows still work.

How can I tell VIM to apply the mapping in this mode as well?

Comment: Mappings do not working in paste mode. Shouldn't be spending any time in paste mode anyways.

Comment: @FDinoff I can accept this as the answer if you post it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mappings do not work in paste mode. There is no way to work around that.

You should only be in paste mode for very short periods of time when you are pasting stuff.